# In Access, how can I make it so values in a ComboBox are hidden, but show up as matches in the combo box's search box?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

In my database, I have a table of "Suppliers" and they have a field called Active.

In a form in MS-Access 2010, I have a bunch of fields and I have a Combo Box for selecting Suppliers.  However, I would like the Suppliers who are not active to be not visible while scrolling through the possible Suppliers, but if they type in the search box a name that matches the supplier, I would like them to become visible or popup as a match.

How can I do this?  I am willing to implement VBA.  I apologize if I am misunderstanding Combo Boxes.

Edit: Edited the question to make a little more sense.

Comment: This is probably the wrong place to ask. SO is there for programming problems, not for finding functions and options in specific programs.

Comment: I'm going to assume you're referring to the tag I chose.  I added vba then to the tags  I just mentioned vba in case there wasn't any solution to my problem that wouldn't require vba.

Comment: IF it's not a big deal that they can type them in, then why bother hiding them in the first place? Going through the extra steps to get a desired choice is not keeping it simple.

Comment: I mainly want them to focus on getting Active Suppliers, but there is the case an Asset is now using an inactive supplier.  The combobox should only show active suppliers, but there still needs to be acknowledgement for inactive suppliers.   Yes, this is a bit silly and its an awkward approach as I could just have a checkbox for filtering out inactive suppliers, but I was just curious if this appraoch was possible and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want items of the searchlist to show up as you type they MUST be in the list.

However, you can sort the list so that the inactive ones appear at the end.

```
SELECT Supplier, Active FROM tblSuppliers ORDER BY Active, Supplier
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the input.  To be honest, that probably makes more sense (having them sorted by active) than what I was going for.

I really am sorry that my question was kinda dumb.